# Margins between components inside LinearLayout

Tags: android

There are two buttons inside the `LinearLayout`

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="90dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button3"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/btn_show" />

        <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/floatingActionButton3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:paddingLeft="40dp"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_menu" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

I need the floating action button to be located with an offset of 8dp from the right edge. But it's kind of stuck to the first button and that I don't set padding Left or margin Left, they are still located together.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Might be better to use `RelativeLayout` instead with `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"` and `android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"` to make it locate on the right edge. Then, use `android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"` and `android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"` to set the margins (note that `sp` is recommended rather than `dp`).

Answer (score 3):

You're using `LinearLayout` with horizontal orientation and that's why they'll always be side-by-side no matter what you do. Try reading about layouts and how they work.

You can wrap your content around a `FrameLayout` and then use gravity and layout gravity for the button as `bottom|end`.

That should work.

Answer (score 1):

Google's suggestion for page design is from [constraint-layout](https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout)
For better, easier and even more efficient design

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

and this for your fab

```
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
```